# Run Unreal tournament on ubuntu 15

Tags: gtk

this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games/Native/UnrealTournament

seems to be out of date : it says in the Troubleshooting category, under "Error loading shared libraries" which is the error I get that I should download and dpkg three libraries. the second of which is incompatible with my ubuntu and fails to install with this error code under terminal :

```
Setting up libglib1.2ldbl:i386 (1.2.10-19build1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk1.2:i386:
libgtk1.2:i386 depends on libgtk1.2-common (>= 1.2.10-18.1build2).

dpkg: error processing package libgtk1.2:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgtk1.2:i386
```

and in the Software Center :

```
(Reading database ... 229960 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk1.2:i386 (1.2.10-18.1build2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk1.2:i386:
libgtk1.2:i386 depends on libgtk1.2-common (>= 1.2.10-18.1build2).

dpkg: error processing package libgtk1.2:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgtk1.2:i386
```

from where I stand it looks like libgtk1.2:i386 cannot install no matter what.

Is there any hopes to be able to run ut?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try following this user's response: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2089790&p=12430257#post12430257

You'll have to edit the part where he points the package source to a maverick repo, to you'r current Ubuntu release (also, the gpg key part will differ).

I haven't tried this out yet, but it certainly looks promising.